# auto trigger a function with .animate in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am on a jQuery project and stuck at some point.
I'm using jQuery `.animate()`  i.e: `$(".planeid").animate({top:'590px'},1000);` 
where initially the top value is `0`.

It's possible to trigger a task when the `top` property value reaches `200`?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by using `step` call back of animate function.

```
$(".planeid").animate({top:'590px'},
                      { 
                       duration : 1000 , 
                       step : function(currentValue){
                           if(currentValue === 200)
                            {
                              //your code here.
                            }
                       }});
```

Comment: I'M USING alert(currentValue); under if condition which is not executing, any idea why

Comment: @prayas just make an alert outside that if()

Comment: great thanks it is now showing the values, but i want to execute an action only after that value, because of which I used "if" contition

Comment: @prayas Can you make a simple demo of that in jsfiddle.net.? so that we could fix your issue easily.?

Comment: @prayas Glad to help.! consider this as accepted if you wish. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, because there's no guarantee that the animated value will ever precisely equal a given value as it's animating, checking that the animated value/property exceeds the check-point rather than equalling it:

```
$(".planeid").animate({
    top: '590px'
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function () {
        // caching the relevant node, since we're using it a lot:
        var _t = this;
        // using parseInt() here, but parseFloat could be used instead:
        if (parseInt(_t.style.top, 10) > parseInt(_t.getAttribute('data-observe'), 10)) {
            console.log('passed ' + _t.getAttribute('data-observe') + ' (' + _t.style.top + ')');
            // removing the attribute in order to allow the code to be executed only
            // once per animation (rather than constantly once it's animated beyond
            // the given point
            _t.removeAttribute('data-observe');
        }
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gqc4L/).

The above will run only once (as the `data-observe` attribute is removed once it's matched the `if` condition the first time); to run multiple times, however, I'd suggest:

```
// using prop() to set the flag to keep observing (on subsequent animations):
$(".planeid").prop('keepObserving', true).animate({
    top: '590px'
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function () {
        var _t = this;
        if (parseInt(_t.style.top, 10) > parseInt(_t.getAttribute('data-observe'), 10) && _t.keepObserving) {
            console.log('passed ' + _t.getAttribute('data-observe') + ' (' + _t.style.top + ')');
            // setting the flag to false, so it runs only once per animation
            // not on every increment after passing the given point:
            _t.keepObserving = false;
        }
    },
    complete: function(){
        // once the animation is complete we reset the flag so it will
        // all re-run on every subsequent animation:
        this.keepObserving = true;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gqc4L/1/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).
  - [`Node.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
  - [`Node.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.removeAttribute).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Well no, did you read my answer? I explicitly pointed out that there's no guarantee that `currentValue` will ever equal 200, which is why I used `>` instead of `===`. Also `currentValue` isn't what you seem to think it is.